# ASP.Net Web.Config transform naming issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, web-config-transform

I have an ASP.Net project which utilizes the web.config transforms.  To facilitate this I have built a structure like so:

```
web.base.config
    web.debug.config
    web.QA.config
    web.release.config
    web.config
```

The `web.base.config` contains the untransformed base of the web.config data, while the `web.[ENVIRONMENT].config` contains the transform data based upon the current build configuration.  The `web.config` contains the transform result that gets loaded at runtime.

This works really well for us and has been very nice for staging changes.

However there's a small issue that I've thus far been working around manually:  When I update my NuGet dependencies they apply their transforms to the `web.config` file, which upon build then gets blown away with the transformations from my other configs.

I have looked into a few different ways of fixing this and I haven't had any luck...Any ideas?

For the record, this is how I achieved the above web.config schema (in the project file):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Web.base.config">
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.base.Local.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.base.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.base.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.base.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.base.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.base.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.base.QA.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.base.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <Content Include="Web.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.base.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="attrib -r Web.config" />
    <TransformXml Source="web.base.config" Transform="web.base.$(Configuration).config" Destination="web.config" StackTrace="true" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Can you add some specifics? This should be a non-issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: The issue is that the web.base.config is what should be updated by nuget, rather than the web.config.  But as far as I can tell there is no way to set that up on a project specific level (as this is a team project with many engineers).  Right now on build, everything is fine - but on nuget update, the web.config gets updated with the package changes and then blown away on the next build.  I'm currently gatekeeping all nuget changes and manually copying them on update to the web.base.config, but we want to eliminate this step.

Comment: Ahh.. I see now. I think you've set it up backwards. By design, `web.config` should contain all your base/default/debug values. You then "overrride" those with transforms (based on environment, configuration or whatever criteria you choose). I don't think there is any setting that'd let you say that use web.base.config instead of web.config. Your best bet is to follow the convention.

Comment: Yeah - I would love to do that, but the problem is that the web.config has to contain the transformation results, rather than the untransformed data...unless you are saying that the convention is to apply the transforms for the web.config against and into the web.config?

Comment: Yep. E.g. web.config: `<add key="IsDebug" value="true" />`. web.release.config: `<add key="IsDebug" value="false"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" /> `

Comment: Ahhh - that makes sense...I suppose it was the semi-self-referencing-file that was throwing me off to use the web.base.config instead...if you want to post this as an answer I would be happy to mark it as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design, `web.config` should contain all your base/default/debug values. You then "overrride" those with transforms (based on environment, configuration or whatever criteria you choose). I don't think there is any setting that'd let you say that use `web.base.config` instead of `web.config`. Your best bet is to follow the convention.

E.g. 
**web.config**

```
<add key="IsDebug" value="true" />
```

**web.release.config**

```
<add key="IsDebug" value="false"  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```